# incompatible pointer types assigning to 'void (*)(void *)' from 'int (int *)'

Tags: c, pointers

I have written code in C below, but get a warning on `p = getNext;`

> incompatible pointer types assigning to 'void (*)(void *)' from 'int (int *)'

```
int getNext(int *p){
    return rand();
}
void testFunc(void (* p)(void *)){
    printf("right!\n");
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    void (*p)(void *);
    p = getNext;
    testFunc(p);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to solve it by

```
p = (void *)getNext;
```

It works. But I have no idea why it works. Does (void *) cast the `getNext` to a new function that can return undefined type of data?
Can someone explains it?

Comment: Think a little bit about what you're trying to do. Why do you think you get the error message? What makes you think the different types of `p` and `getNext` would work together? And that cast *will* cause your code to have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: The syntax of a function pointer definition is `<return_type> (*<pointer_name>) (function_arguments);`. The return type and function arguments do not fit to your function `getNext`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getNext` is a function of type `int getNext(int *p)`, and it decays to a pointer of to a function of type `int (*)(int *)`. this is *incompatible* with your other pointer type, and you would need a cast. Hence:

```
void (*p)(void *);
p = (void (*)(void*))getNext;
```

The problem is that when you call the function through the pointer you must cast it back to the original type... Perhaps you meant to use `int (*p)(int *);` everywhere.

---

A typedef simplifies handling function pointers. For example:

```
typedef int (*CALLBACK)(int *);

void testFunc(CALLBACK p){
    printf("right!\n");
}

...
    CALLBACK p = getNext;
    testFunc(p);
```

---

The converting to `void *` and then to a function is doubly invalid when it comes to standard C, but it is allowed as an extension in POSIX, which has the `dlsym` function that returns a `void *` that could point to a function or an object alike.

Comment: Note the name CALLBACK is already used on Windows, so you might need to choose a different name.